# CAML query with In operator

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, caml-query, splistitem, caml

I'm trying to use CAML query with `In` operator since it's easyer to build then `Or` conditions.

Here is my CAML

```
    <View Scope="RecursiveAll">
<Query>
<Where>
<In>
<FieldRef Name="Title" />
<values>
    <Value Type="Text">A1</Value>
    <Value Type="Text">NPD</Value>
    <Value Type="Text">NPD2</Value>
</values>
</In>
</Where>
</Query>
</View>
```

Unfortunately it returns nothing but if I search the values one by one it works. What is my mistake?

Here is the complete CSOM code

```
var xmlQuery = '<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query><Where><In><FieldRef Name="Title" /><values>';
        $("select[title='Perf Decl selected values'] option").each(function(){
            xmlQuery += '<Value Type="Text"><![CDATA[' + this.text + ']]></Value>'; 
        });
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web();
        var lists = web.get_lists(); 
        var listId = "BEE6E734-9B7D-4852-ACE2-E641D6EDE2A3";// perf decl list
        var list = lists.getById(listId);
        var query=new SP.CamlQuery();
        xmlQuery += '</values></In></Where></Query></View>';
        alert( xmlQuery  );
        query.set_viewXml(xmlQuery);
        resultsPD = list.getItems(query);
        context.load(resultsPD);
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceededPerfDecl), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailedPerfDecl)); 

        function onQueryFailedPerfDecl(sender, args) {
        alert('Request PerfDecl failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        flag = false;
    }

    function onQuerySucceededPerfDecl(sender, args) {
    alert('succed');
        var listItemInfo = '';
        var listItemEnumerator = resultsPD.getEnumerator();

        var cptR = 0;
        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            if(cptR  == 0){
                tabPerf += "<table>";
            }
            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            tabPerf += "<tr><td>" + oListItem.get_item('Title') +"</td><td>" + oListItem.get_item('Perf_x0020_Decl') + "</td></tr>";
            alert('movenex');
            cptR++;
        }
        if(cptR  > 0){
            tabPerf += "</table>";
        }else{
            tabPerf += "";
        }
        $("input[title='PerfDeclTab']").val(tabPerf);
        flag = true;
        alert("tabPerf  == " + tabPerf);
        return flag;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CAML schema is case-sensitive. You need to change `<values>` to `<Values>`.

In general all elements are capitalized, but for some reason there are elements like `<CHOICES>` written in uppercase. When in doubt, best reffer to [Collaborative Application Markup Language (CAML) schemas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms462365.aspx) on MSDN.